# js не работает цикл

Tags: javascript

Задумка в симуляции броска 2х кубиков и увеличении высоты соответствующих блоков. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку выдается только 1 случайное число, а цикл (100 бросков) не работает.

JS

```
var height2 = 0;
var height3 = 0;
var height4 = 0;
var height5 = 0;
var height6 = 0;
var height7 = 0;
var height8 = 0;
var height9 = 0;
var height10 = 0;
var height11 = 0;
var height12 = 0;

function cubesRandom() { 
  for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var z = x+y;

  if (z==2) {  
  height2 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column2").style.height =  height2 + "px";
  return height2;
  }

  else if (z==3) {  
  height3 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column3").style.height =  height3 + "px";
  return height3;
  }

  else if (z==4) {  
  height4 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column4").style.height =  height4 + "px";
  return height4;
  }

  else if (z==5) {  
  height5 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column5").style.height =  height5 + "px";
  return height5;
  }

  else if (z==6) {  
  height6 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column6").style.height =  height6 + "px";
  return height6;
  }

  else if (z==7) {  
  height7 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column7").style.height =  height7 + "px";
  return height7;
  }

  else if (z==8) {  
  height8 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column8").style.height =  height8 + "px";
  return height8;
  }

  else if (z==9) {  
  height9 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column9").style.height =  height9 + "px";
  return height9;
  }

  else if (z==10) {  
  height10 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column10").style.height =  height10 + "px";
  return height10;
  }

  else if (z==11) {  
  height11 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column11").style.height =  height11 + "px";
  return height11;
  }

  else {  
  height12 += 1;
  document.getElementById("column12").style.height =  height12 + "px";
  return height12;
  };
  };
 }
```

Comment: Ну так return срабатывает и выходит из функции. Вам надо или return'ы убрать или цикл вынести из функции наружу.

Comment: спасибо большое! Почему-то думал, что без return не будет сохраняться текущее значение height

Answer (score 1):

Подправил)

```js
var heights = [];

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


async function cubesRandom(count, attempts) {
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    heights[i] = 0;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'column' + i;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * count / 2) + 1;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * count / 2) + 1;
    var z = x + y;
    var div = document.getElementById('column' + z);
    if (div) div.style.height = ++heights[z] + 'px';
    await sleep(10);
  };
}

cubesRandom(15, 100);
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 5px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сделаль

```js
var height2 = 0;
var height3 = 0;
var height4 = 0;
var height5 = 0;
var height6 = 0;
var height7 = 0;
var height8 = 0;
var height9 = 0;
var height10 = 0;
var height11 = 0;
var height12 = 0;

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


async function cubesRandom() { 
  for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var z = x+y;

    if (z==2) {  
    height2 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column2").style.height =  height2 + "px";
    
    }

    else if (z==3) {  
    height3 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column3").style.height =  height3 + "px";
 
    }

    else if (z==4) {  
    height4 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column4").style.height =  height4 + "px";
    
    }

    else if (z==5) {  
    height5 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column5").style.height =  height5 + "px";
  
    }

    else if (z==6) {  
    height6 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column6").style.height =  height6 + "px";
    
    }

    else if (z==7) {  
    height7 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column7").style.height =  height7 + "px";
   
    }

    else if (z==8) {  
    height8 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column8").style.height =  height8 + "px";
    
    }

    else if (z==9) {  
    height9 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column9").style.height =  height9 + "px";
 
    }

    else if (z==10) {  
    height10 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column10").style.height =  height10 + "px";
    
    }

    else if (z==11) {  
    height11 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column11").style.height =  height11 + "px";
    
    }

    else {  
    height12 += 1;
    document.getElementById("column12").style.height =  height12 + "px";
   
    };
    await sleep(10);
  };
 }

var el2 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el3 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el4 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el5 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el6 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el7 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el8 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el9 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el10 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el11 = document.createElement("p"); 
var el12 = document.createElement("p");
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 5px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="cubesRandom()">
<div id="column2"></div>
<div id="column3"></div>
<div id="column4"></div>
<div id="column5"></div>
<div id="column6"></div>
<div id="column7"></div>
<div id="column8"></div>
<div id="column9"></div>
<div id="column10"></div>
<div id="column11"></div>
<div id="column12"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

рандом неравномерный